# In Snowflake, and in SQL Server, how do I unpivot 83 columns into 83 rows?

Tags: sql-server-2016, unpivot, snowflake

I need to compare the SUMs of 83 columns in my source table (in SQL Server) to the SUMs of 83 columns in my target table (in Snowflake) to see if the SUMs of the source and target table columns match. So far, I have queried the SUMs of the 83 columns in the target table in Snowflake. I've got the headers for each column and below that one row with the SUMs of each column. I'd like to UNPIVOT this data, so I end up with two columns: the first column with the column names in rows, and the second column with the SUMs of each column in rows. I'm thinking, if I can do this in the source and target, I can bring the UNPIVOTed columns for source and target into Microsoft Access, or Excel, and see if they match each other. But I don't know how to UNPIVOT the data. I'm wondering if anyone out there can tell me.